# Specify "NEXT VALUE" for INSERT statement using identity column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

Consider the following table and SQL from [Microsoft's INSERT documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381(v=sql.105).aspx#ColumnValues) that deals with IDENTITY columns:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T1 (column_1 int IDENTITY, column_2 VARCHAR(30));
GO

INSERT T1 (column_2) VALUES ('Row #2');
```

The `INSERT` statement does not specify `column_1` as a column of the table, and SQL Server auto-populates the next value for that identity column. This is the normal way identity columns are handled.

How can I have the same behavior, while also specifying the column name?

For example, I'm looking for *something* like:

```
INSERT INTO T1 (column_1, column_2) 
VALUES (NEXT VALUE, 'Row #3');
GO
```

I don't believe `NEXT VALUE` works here, but is there something that does work?  Is there a key token or function that will indicate that the identity column should be used?

Note: the reason I ask is that the framework I'm using requires all columns to be specified in the column list.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that. Is this framework a popular thing? Are you sure that it has that restriction?

Comment: The framework is not open source, and is not fixable in this manner.

Comment: your framework might have an option to use store procedure for insert, i belive it will be easier way to go that road.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are on SQL Server 2012 and later, you can use sequence. But you must remove the `IDENTITY` property from `Column1` first. This can only be done by copy-and-rename a new table.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE Column1_Sequence
    AS int
    START WITH 0;

CREATE TABLE T1
(
    Column1     int DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR Column1_Sequence) PRIMARY KEY
,   Column2     nvarchar(30)
)
```

After that, you can insert data into the table in 2 ways:

```
INSERT INTO T1 (Column1, Column2)
    SELECT      NEXT VALUE FOR Column1_Sequence
            ,   'Row #2'

INSERT INTO T1 (Column2)
    SELECT      'Hello world'
```

Answer (score 1):

Can  you set the identity insert on before inserting and then set the identity insert off

Comment: Yes, but I want the identity column to generate the ID.  I don't want to supply it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set value for identity column unless you set identity_insert on for this table (one at time). Some examples:

```
create table #tmp (id int identity(1,1), name varchar(10))

insert #tmp (id,name) values (2,'test')
--error Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table '#tmp

set identity_insert #tmp on --for one table in DB
insert #tmp (id,name) values (2,'qwas')
select * from #tmp
set identity_insert #tmp off -- good practice
--works

--see current identity value
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT ('#tmp') AS Current_Identity;

--Reset identity value
DBCC CHECKIDENT (#tmp, RESEED, 999)
--next insert will be 1000
```

Of course, if you reset next identity to a value which conflicts with PK (common usage of identity) you will have `Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint` error

Comment: Actually you can. SET IDENTITY INSERT ON

Comment: @TomTom did I say something opposite? I showed how and when you can use and override identity constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure there is no way to do that with SQL Server. Two workarounds that I can think of:

1. Fix the library if possible.
2. If the library supports it, you can create a view and INSERT into that instead. For example:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE MyTable
   (
       ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
       SomeColumn VARCHAR(100)
   )

   GO
   CREATE VIEW MyTableView
   AS
   SELECT SomeColumn
   FROM MyTable

   GO
   INSERT INTO MyTableView (SomeColumn) VALUES ('Test')
   ```