# Error when clicking on button to save value in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
public partial class SignUp : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void BtSignup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabaseConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Users values('"+TbUname.Text+"', '"+TbPass.Text+"','"+TbEmail.Text+"', '"+TbName.Text+"')",con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //error in this line
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: so whats the errorcode?

Comment: What happens when your user puts an apostrophe in one of the text boxes?  You need to use parameters

Comment: Whats the error????

Comment: print the sql command or query and see what's wrong there

Comment: when user puts apostrophe it shows error like "incorrect syntax near..  unclosed quotation mark after the character string  )'    "

Comment: @MohammedSaquibSiddique, is that the error your seeing or is that just ANOTHER error?

Comment: maybe you get an error because you have want to insert more or less values then columns.   Iam also not sure if ur ' and " is in the right order, what says the errorcode

Comment: @KyleB this is another error

Comment: @MohammedSaquibSiddique could you post complete error message in your original post.

Comment: That is a bad question. You provided no details. Please edit the question and include all the details in the question and describe how you get the problem and what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two likely problems that I can see without you adding the error code.

1. is that you are missing the column names in your insert statement.
2. is that a user is putting an apostrophe in one of your text boxes.  This is a SQL Injection vulnerability.

Try something similar to this instead:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
{
    // add the columns and do not concatenate strings in SQL statements
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"insert into Users 
         (username, password, email, name) 
           values 
         (@username, @password, @email, @name)", con);

    // add values by using sql parameters
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TbUname.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TbPass.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TbEmail.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TbName.Text);

    con.Open();

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'E:\VS_PROJECTS\SAMPLEWEBSITE\APP_DATA\MYDATABASE.MDF.dbo.Users'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated. (This error shows according to your code )

Comment: @MohammedSaquibSiddique, for "Cannot insert the value NULL", see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013313/why-is-sql-server-throwing-this-error-cannot-insert-the-value-null-into-column

Answer (score 0):

`insert into Users (dbcol1, dbcol2, dbcol3, dbcol4)values('"+TbUname.Text+"', '"+TbPass.Text+"','"+TbEmail.Text+"', '"+TbName.Text+"')`

here dbcol is means it your table coloumn name....

try this..

and also in your database table id is not allowing null values. i think your coloumn(id) is primary key. you can`t pass null either you change or else you should pass value in (id)coloumn..