# Why EF Core 5 does not create "Primary Key Autoincrement" using "[Key]" attribute on "Id" property of my entity "Address"?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, sqlexception

I am using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` v5.0.3 in my VS 2019 project (running on .NET Core 3.1).

As you can see in the entity class `Address` the first property `int Id` has the attribute `[Key]`:

```
[Index(nameof(Country))]
[Index(nameof(ZIP))]
[Index(nameof(City))]
public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
    public DateTime ChangedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;

    [StringLength(EFConst.MAX_LEN_COUNTRY)]
    public string Country { get; set; }     
    
    [StringLength(EFConst.MAX_LEN_ZIP)]
    public string ZIP { get; set; }
    
    [StringLength(EFConst.MAX_LEN_CITY)]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [StringLength(EFConst.MAX_LEN_STREET)]
    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

But after the database schema is created, I don't see neither `PRIMARY KEY` nor `AUTOINCREMENT` in the CREATE TABLE script using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio as you can see here:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Addresses]
(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RowVersion] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedAt] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ChangedAt] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Country] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
    [ZIP] [nvarchar](32) NULL,
    [City] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
    [Street] [nvarchar](128) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Addresses] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Now, when this code is executed:

```
var addr1 = db.Addresses.Add(new Address
{
    Country = "SampleCountry",
    City = "SampleCity",
    ZIP = "12345",
    Street = "SampleStreet 123"
});

db.SaveChanges();
```

I get this exception at `db.SaveChanges()`:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details
>
> Inner Exception
>
> SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table 'NSA.dbo.Addresses'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

I am not wondering why the exception is thrown.

Why is the column `ID` in table `Addresses` not defined as `PRIMARY AUTOINCREMENT`?

I already have searched/googled the whole internet... and reached the borders of it.

None of the [solutions on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013313/why-is-sql-server-throwing-this-error-cannot-insert-the-value-null-into-column) (or other places) worked for me!
As explained in [official documentation of EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations) my simple project should work!

I already made step-by-step try-and-error following experiments (single and combination of some) with no success:

- Using "Data Annotations" (attributes):

  - `[Key]`
  - `[Required]`
  - `[Required, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`
  - `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`
- Renaming `Id` to `AddressId` (+ combinations of using attributes above)
- Using Fluent API by overriding `void OnModelCreating(...)` and using  `modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().HasKey(a => a.Id);`
- Re-defining property `Id` as: `int? Id`, `int ID`, `int? ID`, `int AddressId`, `int? AddressId`, `int AddressID`, and `int? AddressID`

Am I doing something wrong?

How can I define the "Id" property of "Address" class as PRIMARY KEY + AUTOINCREMENT by using EF Core?

Thank you!

Comment: What **database** are you using in the backend?? SQL Server for instance **doesn't** have an `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword - it's called `IDENTITY` instead.

Comment: @marc_s I am using SQL EXPRESS (MSSQL 15). There is also no "IDENTITY" keyword in the SQL create script!

Comment: did you do another migration and database update after using this annotation ? [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

Comment: @MohamedAdel You are right! The problem was I did not delete the db before re-creating it (facepalm). Thank you very much for your help and saving my day.

Comment: @user14867525 you are welcome, I added as answer please accept it for further needs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you do another migration and database update after using this annotation ?

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

You just need to do another migration and update your DB

Comment: This should not be necessary. The documentation says, "By convention, a property named Id or <type name>Id will be configured as the primary key of an entity."

Answer (score 2):

Thank to @MohamedAdel, I solved the problem deleting the database and re-created it. Now the "ID" column is defined as

```mssql
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
```

and everything works great.
Thank you all for your help!