# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'customer_id' but customer_id does have value

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, node-mssql

I'm using [MSSQL bulk](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql#bulk-table-options-callback) function to insert data into the database. The column `customer_id`  does exist in the table.

When I debug and see the values that's in `table.rows.push(map)`, I can see property `customer_id`  and it has a integer value. I also debugged `await request.bulk(table)` and I can see property `customer_id`  and it has a integer value.

I don't know why I'm getting the following error message.

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'customer_id', table
> 'api.dbo.givers'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT  fails."

```
try {
  let results = [];
  var response = fs
    .createReadStream('C:\\data\\givers.csv')
    .pipe(parse({ delimiter: ',', from_line: 2 }))
    .on('data', function (row) {
      results.push(row);
    });
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    response.on('end', async () => {
      let pool = await sql.connect(connectionConfig);
      const table = new sql.Table('givers');
      table.create = false;
      table.columns.add('customer_id', sql.Int, { nullable: false });
      table.columns.add('source_giver_id', sql.VarChar, { nullable: false });
      ...

      results.forEach((row) => {
        const map = [];
        map['customer_id'] = customer_id;
        map['last_updated'] = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
        ...
        table.rows.push(map);
      });

      const request = new sql.Request(pool);
      await request.bulk(table); //error get's thrown here

      resolve(results.length);
    });
    response.on('error', reject);
  });
} catch (err) {
  if (err) return err;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is SQL server throwing this error: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013313/why-is-sql-server-throwing-this-error-cannot-insert-the-value-null-into-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to replicate this issue. I've been playing around and when I change `const map = [];` to `const map = {};` it worked. I don't know why `const map = [];` didn't work because `table.rows` is an interface of `interface Array<T> extends RelativeIndexable<T> {}`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see where the customer_id field is coming from in the foreach. You should read the customer_id in the row

```
results.forEach((row) => {
  const map = [];
  map["customer_id"] = row.customer_id;
  table.rows.push(map);
});
```

I think it will work if you use it this way, because customer_id data is not available so it will be null.